# how can we use template with virtual function for abstraction in cpp?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Unfortunately, I have faced a challenge since I can't use abstraction and templates simultaneously. The idea is to keep the parent class as general as possible so we put the general form of two member functions as an abstraction in the parent class.
Then, I wanted to define these functions in the child class how I wanted them to be. But the problem arises when I want to keep the parent template not even after the declaration of child class not make it  as soon as I go to the child class. Please someone show me a solution if there are any?

```
template <class y2>
class parrennt
{
    public:
    y2 numb;
    virtual y2 funcc3()=0;
    virtual y2 funcc4()=0;

};

template <class y2>
class chilld : public parrennt <double> // I want to keep it <class y2> if its possible
{
    public:
    virtual y2 funcc3 () { return numb*2;}
    virtual y2 funcc4 () { return numb*3;}

};
```

Comment: So you want `class chilld : public parrennt <y2>`?

Answer (score 0):

There are some tricky parts in the name lookup of base class members - especially when the base class depends on the template parameter, like here. Templates have two-phase name lookup: first when the template is compiled, and then for [*dependent names*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) an additional lookup once template parameters are known.

`numb` is not obviously dependent on `y2`, so it will be looked up in `class chilld` only.

The solution is very simple. Write `this->numb`. Since `this` has type `child<y2>*`, it is dependent on `y2`, and the name lookup of `this->numb` is delayed till the second phase where `y2` is known, and also `parent<y2>`